# xcode crash in firebase listener block, inside React Native native module

Tags: firebase, react-native, xcode7.3

I'm exposing Firebase through a Native Module for use inside React Native javascript. (To utilize Firebase offline capabilities):

```
@objc func load() -> Void{
    let urlStr = "xxxxx"
    self.ref = Firebase(url:urlStr)
    self.ref?.keepSynced(true)
    self.ref?.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if(!snapshot.exists()){
           print("no data")
        } else {
            self.bridge?.eventDispatcher.sendAppEventWithName( "DataChange", body: snapshot.value ) // ***crashes here***
        }
    })
}
```

.m bridge file:

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(DataSource, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(load)

@end
```

but Xcode keep crashing whenever reaching  this callback block. the app itself keeps running fine. Firebase data real-time sync is working as well. Just annoying to be not possible to debug in Xcode.

tried adding methodQueue to run this module in main thread, no effect.

xcode 7.3, react-native 0.23 in cocoapods

any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more detailed in where it's crashing? Did you create a bridging file?

Comment: edited bridge file. it is crashing in the last line, sendAppEventWithName call.

Comment: Try sendDeviceEventWithName instead of sendAppEventWithName

Comment: I recreated the whole project. Now xcode didn't crash. When this exception happens, turns out eventDispatcher is nil. How could this happens sometimes but now always?